# S6 Text Bubbles

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-6

Ever since I got my s6 I have not been able to change the color of my text bubbles. I shut of the enhanced messaging and the settings only have background instead of backgrounds and bubbles. How can I get it to where I can change the text bubbles?